# how to overload Spring PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer's processProperties() method

Tags: spring

My requirement is as given below :
"we have a load a big properties file using Spring and then loop through it .
While looping we have to check the very first column of properties file for some particular values. 
As soon as we find those values we have to print that value  and continue this printing process till the very end."

For this i finally able to build a code like below :

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Properties;
import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class SpringPropertiesUtil extends PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer {

    private static Map<String, String> propertiesMap;
    private static String keyToFind = "myProperty";
    // Default as in PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer
    private int springSystemPropertiesMode = SYSTEM_PROPERTIES_MODE_FALLBACK;

    @Override
    public void setSystemPropertiesMode(int systemPropertiesMode) {
        super.setSystemPropertiesMode(systemPropertiesMode);
        springSystemPropertiesMode = systemPropertiesMode;
    }

    @Override
    protected void processProperties(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory, Properties props) throws BeansException {

        super.processProperties(beanFactory, props);

        for (Object key : props.keySet()) {
            String keyStr = key.toString();         
            if(keyStr.equals(keyToFind))    {
            String valueStr = resolvePlaceholder(keyStr, props, springSystemPropertiesMode);
            System.out.println(valueStr);      
            }         
        }
    }

    public String getProperty(String name) {
        return propertiesMap.get(name).toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)  {

        ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationContext.xml");

        ((ConfigurableApplicationContext)context).close();
    }

}
```

It is working fine but i am finding a nicer way of doing this if i can overload processProperties() and can pass String keyTofind to this method rather than defining it globally.
Any suggestion is welcome.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to your solution, you could implement a custom property source. I believe this is the mechanism Spring has intended for proprietary "source parsing logic".

The subject is not terribly well documented on the web, but this article gives some insight: http://scottfrederick.cfapps.io/blog/2012/05/22/Custom-PropertySource-in-Spring-3.1---Part-1/